# CANONICAL - Duplicate page issue

Tags: seo, canonical-link

Can someone help me with this problem.

currently google reports that this two link is duplicate.

http://www.ozkidsactivities.com/n/jules-pony-rides-&-mobile-animal-farm/ozkids-36?activityId=1218

http://www.ozkidsactivities.com/n/jules-pony-rides-and-mobile-animal-farm/ozkids-36?activityId=1218

but we already include the canonical tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/n/jules-pony-rides-and-mobile-animal-farm/ozkids-36?activityId=1218" />
```

is there a problem with the relative path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this question can be improved by reformatting the question to more clearly indicate the problem. Commenting here to see if I can come back later and improve. The answer is useful in indicating the problem OP is facing

Answer (score 3):

red,

Canonical URL tags can reference the relative path (see Google's guidelines here - http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html), however, I'd suggest that it's better and safer to use the absolute URL (i.e., including the protocol and fully-formed hostname) - given that many websites tend to be accessible by numerous hostnames (alternative domains, test/development environments with exposed URLs, etc.) it's best to reference the correct absolute URL in order to avoid any adverse incorrect canonisation if/when search engines discover these URLs.

It looks like you've already fixed your solution, though, as well as solving the problem another way by redirecting the ampersand to the 'and'. Good work!